# .NET: ListView blues?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, listview

Selection count, `.SelectedItems.Count`, does not change when 
the `Selected` property is set to true on an item in the `Items` 
collection of a `ListView`.

Example:

```
  lvPept.SelectedItems.Clear()
  lvPept.Items(6).Selected = True
  Dim newLen As Integer = lvPept.SelectedItems.Count
```

`lvPept` is a `ListView` and contains 10 elements.

`newLen` is expected to be 1, but is 0 when the problem occurs
and the `SelectedIndexChanged` event is ***not*** fired. With
other datasets it is 1 as expected and the
SelectedIndexChanged event is fired.

Under what circumstance or in what state can `lvPept` be in
for this to happen? `BeginUpdate`()/`EndUpdate`() is ***not***
used with `lvPept`.

Background:

I am trying to track down a problem one of the users of my
open source .NET application, MSQuant
(http://msquant.sourceforge.net/), encountered.

I have run out of ideas of what could be the cause of this
problem.

The problem is reproducible, and I can reproduce it in my
development environment, Visual Studio 2008. It seems to be
independent of the Windows version (Windows 2000/Windows XP 32 bit/
Windows XP 64 bit), the .NET runtime version (2.0/3.5) and Visual
Studio version (2005/2008).

Other context: the application is written in VB.NET and in
C# and is a Windows Forms application. The source code for the
class in question is at http://shrinkster.com/14bg. The 
form class that the `ListView` is in was initially generated 
by one of earliest official versions of Visual Studio that 
supported .NET, ca. 2002.

Update 1: as I have both a working case and a broken case I 
have compared the content of `lvPept`. The only difference 
except for properties "Handle", "MousePosition" and "TopItem" 
(as it is a different protein with different peptides) is property
"Created". It was False for the broken case. It makes sense 
that a partly constructed object can not function properly, 
but how can it happen?

Update 2: property "Created" being false turned out to be a 
good lead. I think the real problem was doing this at 
**construction** time and not at **form load** time. I have now 
added ASSERTs for property "Created", refactored and changed 
all the operations to happen at form load time. It now works 
as expected and the user with the problem has got a new 
version of the application.

The old bad way had been in there since the application's 
inception in 2002. I am just wondering if some experts could 
throw light on why it worked 99.9% of the time and only 
failed in a few cases and reproducably so.

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting one.

The only thing that I think could make this happen is if the ListView didn't realize that the ListItem had changed it's "Selected" value and therefore doesn't update its selected item collections.

The .SelectedItems property is not necessarily generated each time you get the property - if you reflect the System.Windows.Forms assembly:

```
    if (this.selectedListViewItemCollection == null)
    {
        this.selectedListViewItemCollection = new SelectedListViewItemCollection(this);
    }
    return this.selectedListViewItemCollection;
```

So I'm inclined to think that you're getting an out-of-date selectedListViewItemCollection.

I would try instead of changing the Selected property at the Item level, try instead adding the selected index to the .SelectedIndices property of the ListView and see if that works. That way the ListView isn't relying on picking up a ListViewItem change.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you also have to call ListView.Select() in order to fire the SelectedIndexChanged event.

```
lvPept.SelectedItems.Clear()
lvPept.Items(6).Selected = True
lvPept.Select()
Dim newLen As Integer = lvPept.SelectedItems.Count
```